# How to listen to Fragment Backstack Pop only?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I wanted to know when a Fragment has been pop from backstack.

I have my code as below

```
private void setupChildFragmentPopListener() {
    getChildFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    // Do whatever I want
                }
            });
}
```

However, this code got triggered both when add and pop fragment. How could I have a way to listen only to pop fragment? Or a way to filter out in the `onBackStackChanged()` function if it is not pop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep a count of the backstack entries and compare it everytime your `onBackStackChanged()` is called.

```
private void setupChildFragmentPopListener() {
    getChildFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    int backCount = getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helps!

Answer (score 4):

For Kotlin lovers:

```
supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0) {
        fab.visibility = VISIBLE
    }
    // Other magic
}
```